# Not able to detect touch drag and touch drop events

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to achieve drag drop events in device mode in browsers. My code is only working for browsers. For touch devices it works when I pass only one button id to

> document.getElementById('1Mis');

But I have 6 buttons that can be randomly dragged and dropped. How do I achieve this? I have tried using

> querySelectorAll

but it didn't worked. Also I have tried following code but not able to make it work for different button ids.

```js
var source;
var orderNos = [];

function isbefore(a, b) {
  if (a.parentNode == b.parentNode) {
    for (var cur = a; cur; cur = cur.previousSibling) {
      if (cur === b) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function dragenter(e) {
  var targetelem = e.target;
  if (targetelem.nodeName == "TD") {
    targetelem = targetelem.parentNode;
  }

  if (isbefore(source, targetelem)) {
    targetelem.parentNode.insertBefore(source, targetelem);
  } else {
    targetelem.parentNode.insertBefore(source, targetelem.nextSibling);
  }
}

function dragstart(e) {
  source = e.target;
  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
}


function show() {

  document.getElementById("emailId").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("submitBtn").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("emailSubmit").style.display = "none";

}

function tableArray(event) {
  var arrayOfThisRow = [];
  var tableData = document.getElementsByClassName('gradient-button-4');
  for (var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {
    arrayOfThisRow = tableData[i].innerText;
    orderNos.push(arrayOfThisRow);
    console.log("orderNos", orderNos);

  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <div id="dragbox">
    [dynamictext uid id:uid "xyz-ips snippet='uniqueId'"]
    <tr draggable="true" ondragenter="dragenter(event)" ondragstart="dragstart(event)" class="gradient-button-4">
      <td>Miscommunication & Misinterpretation</td>
    </tr>
    <tr draggable="true" ondragenter="dragenter(event)" ondragstart="dragstart(event)" class="gradient-button-4">
      <td>Communication Delays</td>
    </tr>
    <tr draggable="true" ondragenter="dragenter(event)" ondragstart="dragstart(event)" class="gradient-button-4">
      <td>Scattered Work and Content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr draggable="true" ondragenter="dragenter(event)" ondragstart="dragstart(event)" class="gradient-button-4">
      <td>Sharing Work with Others</td>
    </tr>
    <tr draggable="true" ondragenter="dragenter(event)" ondragstart="dragstart(event)" class="gradient-button-4">
      <td>Getting Feedback and Ideas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr draggable="true" ondragenter="dragenter(event)" ondragstart="dragstart(event)" class="gradient-button-4">
      <td>
        <input type="text" style="border: 1px solid black" placeholder="Any Other?" id="6anyOther" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        [email* emailId id:emailId class:emailId placeholder "Enter your business email Id"]
        <button id="emailSubmit" onclick="show();">Submit</button>
        <button id="submitBtn" onclick="tableArray();">Ok</button></td>
      [hidden clicked_on_link clicked_on_link id:clicked_on_link "No"] [hidden orderNos orderNos id:orderNos] [hidden submission_id submission_id id:submission_id "1"]
    </tr>
  </div>
</table>
```

Comment: Is that the complete code? With `ondragstart` you are calling function `dragStart(event)` that does not exists in your example. `querySelectorAll` may lead to a solution, what exactly "did not work?"

Comment: I have updated the code. ondragstart  works for browser. And for device touchmove works but I want to pass random button ids instead of hard-coding the one button id. Using querySelectorAll  I am getting - Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '#1Mis' is not a valid selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were probably using the `querySelectorAll` wrong. Check this code.

But there is an another bug, it seems that you can drop the buttons on top of each other and they kind of merge which also produces error. That is probably not what you want :)

```js
var orderNos = [];

function dragStart(event) {
  event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", event.target.id);
  console.log("event.target.id", event.target.id);
}

function allowDrop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}

function drop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  data = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  console.log("event.target.id", event.target.id);
  orderNos.push(data);
  console.log("drp", orderNos);
}
// var draggable = document.getElementById("1Mis");
var draggables = document.querySelectorAll(".gradient-button-4");


draggables.forEach((draggable) => {
  wrapper = document.getElementById("dropBox");
  /* the drag function */
  draggable.addEventListener(
    "touchmove",
    function(event) {
      // make the element draggable by giving it an absolute position and modifying the x and y coordinates
      draggable.className = draggable.className + " absolute";
      // put the draggable into the wrapper, because otherwise the position will be relative of the parent element
      wrapper.appendChild(draggable);
      var touch = event.targetTouches[0];
      // Place element where the finger is
      draggable.style.left = touch.pageX - 25 + "px";
      draggable.style.top = touch.pageY - 25 + "px";
      event.preventDefault();
    },
    false
  );
});

draggables.forEach((draggable) => {
  draggable.addEventListener("touchend", function(event) {
    // hide the draggable element, or the elementFromPoint won't find what's underneath
    draggable.style.left = "-1000px";
    draggable.style.top = "-1000px";
    // find the element on the last draggable position
    var endTarget = document.elementFromPoint(
      event.changedTouches[0].pageX,
      event.changedTouches[0].pageY
    );
    // position it relative again and remove the inline styles that aren't needed anymore
    removeClass(draggable, "absolute");
    draggable.removeAttribute("style");
    // put the draggable into it's new home
    if (endTarget !== "undefined") {
      endTarget.appendChild(draggable);
    }
  });
});

// wrapper = document.getElementById('dropBox');
// /* the drag function */
// draggable.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
//   // make the element draggable by giving it an absolute position and modifying the x and y coordinates
//   draggable.className = draggable.className + " absolute";
//   // put the draggable into the wrapper, because otherwise the position will be relative of the parent element
//   wrapper.appendChild(draggable);
//   var touch = event.targetTouches[0];
//   // Place element where the finger is
//   draggable.style.left = touch.pageX - 25 + 'px';
//   draggable.style.top = touch.pageY - 25 + 'px';
//   event.preventDefault();
// }, false);

/* the drop function */
// draggable.addEventListener('touchend', function(event) {
//   // hide the draggable element, or the elementFromPoint won't find what's underneath
//   draggable.style.left = '-1000px';
//   draggable.style.top = '-1000px';
//   // find the element on the last draggable position
//   var endTarget = document.elementFromPoint(
//     event.changedTouches[0].pageX,
//     event.changedTouches[0].pageY
//   );
//   // position it relative again and remove the inline styles that aren't needed anymore
//   removeClass(draggable, 'absolute');
//   draggable.removeAttribute('style');
//   // put the draggable into it's new home
//   if (endTarget !== 'undefined') {
//     endTarget.appendChild(draggable);
//   }
// });

// just a little helper function
function removeClass(e, c) {
  e.className = e.className.replace(
    new RegExp("(?:^|\\s)" + c + "(?!\\S)"),
    ""
  );
}
```

```html
<div class="droptarget" style="border-color:#DE4031;" ondrop="drop(event)">
  <button class="gradient-button-4" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" draggable="true" id="1Mis">Miscommunication & Misinterpretation  </button>
  <button class="gradient-button-4" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" draggable="true" id="2Com">Communication Delays </button>
  <button class="gradient-button-4" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" draggable="true" id="3Sca">Scattered Work and Content  </button>
  <button class="gradient-button-4" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" draggable="true" id="4Sha">Sharing Work with Others  </button>
  <button class="gradient-button-4" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" draggable="true" id="5Get">Getting Feedback and Ideas  </button>
  <input type="text" class="gradient-button-4" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" draggable="true" placeholder="Any Other?" id="6anyOther" />

</div>
<div class="droptarget" id="dropBox" style="border-color:#31CFDE" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
</div>
```

**EDIT:** added simple detection of the case that a button is dropped on top of an another button/input. It checks the element "under" the end position and if it is a type `button` or `input` it just wont be dropped there. You may want to improve this check, so it works for your application.

Depending on you application, you may want to move the buttons that are in the way away to make a room for the newly dropped button. In that case you have to loop thru the buttons and adjust the positions... It is a little more complicated. If you need this, maybe check some libraries for drag&drop that already have this function.

```js
var orderNos = [];

function dragStart(event) {
  event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", event.target.id);
  console.log("event.target.id", event.target.id);
}

function allowDrop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}

function drop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  data = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  console.log("event.target.id", event.target.id);
  orderNos.push(data);
  console.log("drp", orderNos);
}
// var draggable = document.getElementById("1Mis");
var draggables = document.querySelectorAll(".gradient-button-4");



draggables.forEach((draggable) => {
  wrapper = document.getElementById("dropBox");
  /* the drag function */
  draggable.addEventListener(
    "touchmove",
    function(event) {
      // make the element draggable by giving it an absolute position and modifying the x and y coordinates
      draggable.className = draggable.className + " absolute";
      // put the draggable into the wrapper, because otherwise the position will be relative of the parent element
      wrapper.appendChild(draggable);
      var touch = event.targetTouches[0];
      // Place element where the finger is
      draggable.style.left = touch.pageX - 25 + "px";
      draggable.style.top = touch.pageY - 25 + "px";
      event.preventDefault();
    },
    false
  );
});

draggables.forEach((draggable) => {
  draggable.addEventListener("touchend", function(event) {
    // hide the draggable element, or the elementFromPoint won't find what's underneath
    draggable.style.left = "-1000px";
    draggable.style.top = "-1000px";
    // find the element on the last draggable position
    var endTarget = document.elementFromPoint(
      event.changedTouches[0].pageX,
      event.changedTouches[0].pageY
    );
    // position it relative again and remove the inline styles that aren't needed anymore
    removeClass(draggable, "absolute");
    draggable.removeAttribute("style");
    // put the draggable into it's new home

    if (endTarget !== "undefined") {
      // check if I am not trying to drop one button on another button
      const warning = document.querySelector(".warning");
      if (endTarget.nodeName === 'BUTTON' || endTarget.nodeName === 'INPUT') {
        warning.innerHTML = "cant drop me here"
      } else {
        endTarget.appendChild(draggable);
        warning.innerHTML = "I have been dropped"
      }


    }
  });
});


// just a little helper function
function removeClass(e, c) {
  e.className = e.className.replace(
    new RegExp("(?:^|\\s)" + c + "(?!\\S)"),
    ""
  );
}
```

```html
<div class="warning"></div>
<br><br>

<div class="droptarget" style="border-color:#DE4031;" ondrop="drop(event)">
  <button class="gradient-button-4" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" draggable="true" id="1Mis">Miscommunication & Misinterpretation  </button>
  <button class="gradient-button-4" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" draggable="true" id="2Com">Communication Delays </button>
  <button class="gradient-button-4" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" draggable="true" id="3Sca">Scattered Work and Content  </button>
  <button class="gradient-button-4" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" draggable="true" id="4Sha">Sharing Work with Others  </button>
  <button class="gradient-button-4" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" draggable="true" id="5Get">Getting Feedback and Ideas  </button>
  <input type="text" class="gradient-button-4" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" draggable="true" placeholder="Any Other?" id="6anyOther" />

</div>
<div class="droptarget" id="dropBox" style="border-color:#31CFDE" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You so much. I was struggling for this since long... Yes there is this bug of buttons on each other. I didnt found this earlier. How could I fix this?

Comment: I have added a basic collision detection, check the second code snippet.

Comment: So now the requirement has been changed. There is only one dropzone in which user will drag and drop elements on before or after other elements. Touchmove is not working. After touching on any element it relocates outside the dropzone. I have updated my recent code. Please help. TIA